# Procurando e Separando Arquivos Usando .bat

Tags: batch, prompt

> Tenho um processo diário/mensal onde, tenho um .txt que possui uma lista de uns 10.000 ID de arquivos (um ID por linha)

(exemplo_conteudo_arquivo .txt)

> {
>   12345
>   23456
>   34567
>   45678
>   56789
>   }

Cada ID de arquivo **(ex: 12345)** do .txt corresponde a um arquivo .xml (Arquivo_**12345**_0.xml) que está em uma pasta do servidor **(server02)** juntamente com outros 200 mil arquivos .xml que não me interessam.

Quero criar um **.bat** que pelos IDs que possuo no .txt, encontre e jogue em uma pasta somente os .xml com os IDs do .txt.

A grosso modo, a lógica creio eu que ficaria assim.

rode um for para pegar o primeiro ID da primeira linha do .txt e usar como parâmetro pra encontrar o arquivo .xml dentro server02, se encontrar, quero mover esse arquivo pra uma pasta "PASTA_ARQUIVOS_DESEJADOS"

**for (1=0 ; 1>Quantidade_ids_Txt ; i++)**
{
    Variável **XXX** = PEGAR PRIMEIRO ID (QUE CORRESPONDE A i LINHA);

```
Se (PROCURAR .XML QUE O NOME POSSUA *XXX*.xml e encontrar){

    Mover Arquivo_<b>X</b> para C:\USER\PASTA_ARQUIVOS_DESEJADOS

}

Se não{

    registrar no arquivo LOG.txt a string "ARQUIVO XXX não encontrado"

}
```

Por favor, alguém conseguiria me ajudar? Preciso fazer passar essa lógica para uma lógia de .bat . Eu daria conta de fazer isso em um c#, mas em .bat não dou não. Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse comando abaixo você pode modificar as variáveis para se enquadrar ao seu ambiente.

Como não entendo muito do `for` no CMD não tem ainda como remover o log de erro do `{.xml` e do `}.xml` que não serão encontrados.

No `for` cada linha do arquivo será guardado na variável `%%A`, portanto se no arquivo tem o ID **12345** e o nome do arquivo que deve ser copiado é o **Arquivo_12345_0.xml**, no código abaixo dentro do `for` onde tem `%pastaArquivos%%%A%tipo%` você deve modificar para `%pastaArquivos%Arquivo_%%A_0%tipo%`.

```
@echo off

rem Comandos para salvar a data e a hora no log caso tenha interesse.
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('date /t') do set dateLog=%%F
set timeLog=%time%

rem Pasta para onde os arquivos devem ser copiados.
set minhaPasta=C:\MinhaPasta\

rem Arquivo txt que o processo vai ler com o nome dos arquivos.
set meuArquivo=C:\arquivos.txt

rem Caminho com o nome do log que deseja salvar.
set meuLog=C:\meuLog.log

rem Pasta onde estão os arquivos que devem ser copiados, tem que ter a barra no final "\".
set pastaArquivos=C:\MeusArquivos\

rem Extensão dos arquivos.
set tipo=.xml

rem Se a pasta que quer copiar os arquivos não existe esse comando vai criar ela
if not exist %minhaPasta% md %minhaPasta%

rem Caso o arquivo que tem os nomes dos arquivos não exista vai gravar o log informando.
if not exist %meuArquivo% echo Arquivo %meuArquivo% nao encontrado em %dateLog%%timeLog% >> %meuLog%

rem Inicio da verificação
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%meuArquivo%) do (
    if not exist %pastaArquivos%%%A%tipo% (
        echo Arquivo %pastaArquivos%%%A%tipo% nao encontrado em %dateLog%%timeLog% >> %meuLog%
    ) else (
        copy %pastaArquivos%%%A%tipo% %minhaPasta%
    )

)
rem Somente para ver o resultado da cópia dos arquivos, se não quiser remova.
pause
```

Comment: Laercio, fiz um comentário na minha própria pergunta pra poder anexar uma imagem, assim entenderá melhor. Poderia me ajudar com essa questão? Abraços e obrigado pela atenção